# C# switch statement try and catch help required

Tags: c#, exception

Im still in the mist of learning to program, very much lost in that mist actually. could someone help me please to implement this correctly, below is my code, bascially I have a method that takes in a value, tests that value within a switch.

Im jus very confused about how to catch the ArgumentOutOfRangeException correctly :S

```
    public string InTheBox(int x)
    {
        try
        {
            //switch statment to lookup log ID
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Outter";
                case 1:
                    return "Inner";
                case 2:
                    return "Border";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
        }
    }
```

If someone could please explaing to me the cleanest way to catch these exceptions. Thank you!

Comment: Catching an exception simply to throw another one is bad practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you have the try catch block at all? You can simply have

```
public string InTheBox(int x)
{
    //switch statment to lookup log ID
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            return "Outter";
        case 1:
            return "Inner";
        case 2:
            return "Border";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me everyone im sorry for asking such a noob quesiton I just thought it migh have required a try catch :S,

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `try { } catch { }` here - you aren't doing anything to resolve the situation in this method, so you just want to throw the exception (as you do) and leave it to the method which calls this one to deal with the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Don't catch it unless you are going to do something with it:

```
public string InTheBox(int x)
{
    //switch statment to lookup log ID
    switch (x)
    {
            case 0:
                return "Outter";
            case 1:
                return "Inner";
            case 2:
                return "Border";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need try-catch block in this method- it only re-throws the exception so doesn't change anything.

The basic idea of a structural exception handling is that you can handle exception in place other than where it occured. You throw an exception in that method and handle it in the area where you call method.

So your method should look like that

```
public string InTheBox(int x)
{
    //switch statment to lookup log ID
    switch (x)
    {
            case 0:
                return "Outter";
            case 1:
                return "Inner";
            case 2:
                return "Border";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
    }

}
```

However you call it like that:

```
 try
{
   //some code
   InTheBox(someValue);
   //perhaps some other code
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
   //Action you take when exception occurs, perhaps notifying the user.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want this method to do. If it should throw an exception if the argument is invalid, then just remove the try/catch altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings.. The only thing you are missing is that your catch must have a variable to assign the exception to...

replace:

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
        }
```

with

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown value");
        }
```

Of course the situation you have created the `catch/throw ... new` is redundant but I am assuming you are extracting this from a larger scenario in order to set up your question.

I would recommend doing something with the out of range value like this:

```
default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value out of range " + x.toString());
```

This might help you troubleshoot whatever is causing the unexpected value.

Hope this gets you in right direction.

Cheers,

CEC

Comment: Technically, the code in the question would work fine (it does nothing with the exception in the catch block anyway)

Comment: @Chris Ballard, I have never had cause to test that, thanks for your input.

Comment: Please note if your going to raise an ArgumentOutOfRangeException its preferable to use the constructor overload that specifies the argument name. In this case you would be adding information to the new exception (wrt to the original) before throwing it, which perhaps would justify the otherwise redundant catch of an exception only to thow a new one of the same type.

Comment: In your specific example there is no need to define and exception var in the catch as you are not using it (in fact this should generate a hint/warnin when you compile it).